How to exclude some pods from a specific target in Podfile?
In my Flutter app I have a Podfile in which there are two extensions:
// Rest of the Podfile
flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
  target 'RunnerTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
  end
end

target 'Extension' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end

However I receive the following error:

Failed to build iOS app Could not build the precompiled application
for the device.
Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): 'shared' is unavailable in application extensions for iOS: Use view controller based solutions
where appropriate instead.
/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/add_2_calendar-3.0.1/ios/Classes/Add2CalendarPlugin.swift:12:35

Just to test it out, I have tried to remove that package from the pubspec.yaml file, but this problem happens with many other packages.
How can I make it so that specifics packages will be installed in the Runner target, but not in the Extension target?
